# Material Design Toolbar para guardar contenido

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Quiero generar la siguiente toolbar siguiendo la directrices de [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-alerts)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a la izquierda que muestre la `X` , el titulo y a la derecha un botón `Save`

A partir de la plantilla que autogenera Android-Studio, tengo lo siguiente:
Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.webserveis.app.servermonitortools.AddServerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_server);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());

    }
}
```

AndroidMainifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ItemDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_item_detail"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

Me falta insertar el icono `X` con la acción cerrar y ir la actividad anterior, añadir el botón de texto `Save`

Comment: Esta es una pregunta autorespondida? de ser asi, deberia explicar que cosas no funcionaron del codigo que mostras, o que problemas tuviste co el mismo y despues la respuesta. La reportaron como basada en opiniones, y con razon, ya que la pregunta no dice nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para cambiar el icono por defecto de la `toolbar`

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }
    toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());
```

El icono el mismo Android-studio lo lleva, solo se debe cambiar el color a blanco

**Creación del menú**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:title="@string/menu_save"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

**Carga del menú**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_addserver, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**Detectar acción en el menú**

Para ir atrás se puede usar `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` como indica [la documentación oficial](http://ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException:%20Activity%20AddServerActivity%20does%20not%20have%20a%20parent%20activity%20name%20specified) se debe especificar el padre en el `AndroidManifest.xml` en la actividad `android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"` y `android:parentActivityName`

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

> Por naturaleza al retroceder a la actividad padre se recrea de nuevo
>   la actividad, para evitar eso se debe indicar que solo puede haber una
>   instancia de la actividad padre `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_save:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Save action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```